# Realm Sync data on a new device after doing some validation

Tags: ios, realm

I have an app in which I am planning to use synced realm. Would like to know if following is possible:

- UserA creates a new login on device1 and adds data locally. I assume at this point the data is synced and added to the Realm Object Server.
- Now userA logs in on device2 and at this point, I want to make some validations.

  - If validation succeeds, userA can see the data downloaded from RealmObjectServer.
  - But if the validation fails, userA should not be able to see the data downloaded from RealmObjectServer.

Comment: Realm does not provide a function to selectively enable/disable synchronization. In order to achieve it you need to implement it yourself using Professional or Enterprise edition.